# What does ? 2 : 1 passed as date argument for a ruby method mean ?

Tags: ruby, date, module, format

I have the following method in my `date_helper.rb` module

```
def is_holiday_season? date=nil
    @date = date || DateTime.now
    ("14 Nov #{@date.year}".to_date .. "8 Jan #{@date.year}".to_date+1.year).cover?(@date.to_date) ||
    ("14 Nov #{@date.year}".to_date-1.year .. "8 Jan #{@date.year}".to_date).cover?(@date.to_date)
end

  module_function :is_holiday_season?
```

and I am calling this method elsewhere with the following syntax in

```
n = DateHelper.is_holiday_season? ? 2 : 1
```

What does the `'? 2 : 1'` syntax mean?

I assume that is a way to pass a date/time but I could not find the explanation anywhere.

Comment: I got a couple of down votes. Was this a bad question? I'm interested on improving the quality of my questions to make best use of the community. So knowing why this is a bad question will  help me on write better  ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a ternary operator, that can be translated to the `if` statement as follows:

```
n = if DateHelper.is_holiday_season? then 2 else 1 end
```

And in your case, you pass nothing to the `is_holiday_season?` method.

Comment: Thanks for that. I got a couple of down votes. Was this a bad question?

Comment: @vinibol12 well, it would be better to ask people who actually did this)

Comment: Thanks again. I thought I should ask you too since you gave the write answer. It sounded wise to ask you. For the sake of writing better questions from now on.